# Azure DevOps manual agent installation on windows, Steps

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines, devops

I am facing troubles in installing the agent manually If I follow the installation guide in the TFS portal.

These steps not working for me and gives unexpected errors:

[image]

what are the clear steps for that?

Error like:

VS30063:You are not authorized to access http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8080. Failed to
connect.

it's not reasonable because I have administrator privilege in server in TFS all but I can't pass it

Comment: At what step do you get what error?

Comment: Enter server URL > http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8080/

tfs Enter authentication type (press enter for Integrated) > 

Connecting to server ... 
VS30063:You are not authorized to access http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8080. Failed to
connect.  Try again or ctrl-c to quit

Comment: what happens if you type `http://xxx.xx.xx.x:8080` directly into a web browser? what about `https://xxx.xx.xx.x:8080` ?

Comment: `http://xxx.xx.xx.x:8080` gives ==>> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. `https://xxx.xx.xx.x:8080` gives ==>> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: Hi @Mohm Zanaty Did your issue be resolved after added your self as a Team Foundation Administrator?

Comment: no, it did not resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about workaround

1- download agent files

2- put them at any location like C:\agents

3- at PowerShell cd C:\agents

4- .\config.cmd --deploymentgroup --deploymentgroupname "*deploymentgroupname*" --agent *$env:COMPUTERNAME* --runasservice --work '*_work*' --url 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/tfs/' --collectionname '*DefaultCollection*' --projectname '*projectname*' --auth Negotiate;

5- enter username and password